# Django-allauth facebook connect JS SDK

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-authentication, django-allauth

I can successfully use django-allauth to let users login via facebook's OAuth2 mechanism. Now I'd like to enable login via facebook's JS sdk.

The [docs](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth#facebook) say that

> For Facebook both OAuth2 and the Facebook Connect Javascript SDK are supported. You can even mix the two.

Unfortunately, the example code doesn't show how to use the js sdk. By reading the code I found out that I need to set

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk'  # instead of 'oauth2'
    }
}
```

and include the following snippet in the `body` tag of my html template

```
{% include "facebook/fbconnect.html" %}
```

I have also added the following to my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`:

```
allauth.account.context_processors.account
allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount
```

For some reason, this seems not to be enough, since none of the variables to be replaced in `facebook/fbconnect.html` seem to be set, resulting in them being replaced by empty strings. Also, the link produced by `{% provider_login_url 'facebook' method='js_sdk' %}` is just `javascript:FB_login('')`, which is obviously wrong.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out how to do it. Instead of doing

```
{% include "facebook/fbconnect.html" %}
```

I should do

```
{% providers_media_js %}
```